# Lync/Communicator/Sharepoint Presence control using ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint, lync

I'm currently converting our business site from ASP.NET WebForms to ASP.NET MVC3. I'm currently trying to include a presence indicator for my users, in the same way we did using WebForms. In WebForms we used a file called `NameControl.js` (got it from Microsoft) with the site's code as such:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <span class="presence">
        <asp:Image Style="" ID="PresenceImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Common/Images/Shady/Presence/presence_16-unknown.gif" />
    </span>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And the code behind:

```
private void SetPresence(GridViewRow row, int PRESENCE_COL, string sip)
{
    Image presenceImage = row.FindControl("PresenceImage") as Image;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sip))
        presenceImage.Visible = false;
    else
    {
        presenceImage.Attributes.Add("onload", "PresenceControl('" + sip + "');");
    }
}
```

And, this is working fine. So, back to the original question. Currently i'm listing my users using WebGrid, and here is my presence code from my view (inside the WebGrid):

```
grid.Column("Sip", header: "", format: @<text><span class="presence"><img id="@item.ObjectGuid" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Shady/Presence/presence_16-unknown.gif")" onload="PresenceControl("@item.Sip")" alt="" /></span></text>),
```

What currently happens is simple, it's nothing. Escaping the quotes does nothing, leaving them out just the same. When I try using `'@item.Sip'` instead of `"@item.Sip"`, I get an error stating:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'PresenceControl' is undefined

I'm at a loss on what to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

**OK, I found the problem. The Javascript delivered from Microsoft had a syntax error that made the javascript break and not load properly. I stumbled upon it using the web tools in IE9 () watching the console output. Anyway, it's fixed now!**

Comment: i'm very interested, can you provide a link to the microsoft `.js` download?

Comment: Couldnt find the original source I had but, found it on google here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yasinalladin/archive/2007/06/12/ocs-2007-lcs-2005-presence-on-web-application.aspx